# What does ASN.1/BER "Constructed" actually mean?

Tags: asn.1

Lots of places that says bit 6 means constructed.  But what does it mean?

Seams like it means "Explicit" [nn] prefixes that can be added to members of sequences.

But Sequences usually seem to start 30x, but then the next is just the length and then values.  It is said that Sequences are always "constructed", does that mean 10x is illegal?

A clear explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Constructed here means "not primitive", as evidenced by how all those "lots of places" set up a clear dichotomy between those two things. When I try using a search engine, I can find *in a page summary*: "Constructed types are those that combine similar or different primitive types into ordered or unordered groups". I.e., the con*struct*ed types are the ones that have a *struct*ure, and correspond to a `struct` in C-like languages.

Comment: Also, bracketed `[number]` in ASN.1 is used for tags other than the 'universal' ones like INTEGER and BIT STRING. Such tags can be encoded explicitly or implicitly, and explicit tags are always constructed because their V is itself the 'underlying' TLV, while an implicit tag's V is just the underlying V and might be either constructed or primitive depending on the underlying type (which is not encoded). Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690# ?

Comment: To add to what @KarlKnechtel says, "primitive" means what you might refer to as a "scalar" in other contexts: numbers, strings, booleans.  "Constructed" is used for `SEQUENCE`/`SET`, and also for `EXPLICIT` tags, and essentially means that the value that follows has a tag.  So, a tag for `INTEGER` is primitive because the value is just the encoding of a value of `INTEGER` type, but if you have `A ::= [APPLICATION 0] EXPLICIT INTEGER`, then a value of type `A` will start with a constructed tag (and length) then be followed by a primitive `[UNIVERSAL 2]` tag (and length) then the actual value.

Answer (score 5):

EXPLICIT is explained in https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-202102-I/en

Constructed is explained in https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-202102-I/en

Note: constructed is only used used to describe encoding, there is no such thing as a constructed type.

> constructed encoding: A data value encoding in which the contents
> octets are the complete encoding of  one or more data values

---

In a Tag/Length/Value encoding (like ASN.1 BER, CER, DER), Value can either a leaf or a node.

If Value is a leaf, Tag's constructed bit is false

If Value is a node (meaning that Value is in fact another Tag/Lenght/Value), Tag's constructed bit is true

You can find constructed bit set to true in 2 cases (see examples below):

1. You have used EXPLICIT tagging
2. The Type of your Value impose or allow breaking up the value in pieces (then, each piece will have its own Tag/Length

---

*EXPLICIT tagging*

```
Schema DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
  My-Integer1 ::= [0] EXPLICIT INTEGER   -- TLTLV where first T is constructed
  My-Integer2 ::= [1] IMPLICIT INTEGER   -- TLV                                           
END
```

If you send 1 (integer value) using My-Integer1 encoding will be `A003 0201 01` (TLTLV)

If you send 1 (integer value) using My-Integer2 encoding will be `8101 02` (TLV)

---

*Value that can be broken into parts:*

An obvious example would be SEQUENCE OF...

```
Schema DEFINITIONS ::= 
BEGIN
  My-SEQUENCE ::= SEQUENCE OF INTEGER         
END
```

If you send a list of 3 integers (1,2,3) the first tag will be constructed

```
OSS ASN-1Step Version 10.2
Copyright (C) 2021 OSS Nokalva, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This product is licensed for use by "OSS Nokalva, Inc."

C0043I: 0 error messages, 0 warning messages and 0 informatory messages issued.


ASN1STEP: Encoding of value notation  for PDU #1:

Encoding to the file 'data.ber' using BER encoding rule...
My-SEQUENCE SEQUENCE OF: tag = [UNIVERSAL 16] constructed; length = 9
  INTEGER: tag = [UNIVERSAL 2] primitive; length = 1
    1
  INTEGER: tag = [UNIVERSAL 2] primitive; length = 1
    2
  INTEGER: tag = [UNIVERSAL 2] primitive; length = 1
    3
Encoded successfully in 11 bytes:
30090201 01020102 020103
```

A less obvious example is a string (that can be broken into pieces because it can be long). See example 8.23.5.4 in the x690 specification

```
Name ::= VisibleString
```

The value "Jones" can be encoded in 3 different ways:

1. `1A 05 4A6F6E6573` (tag 1A is primitive form)
2. `3A 09 04034A6F6E1 04026573` (tag 3A is constructed form: "Jones" is broken into 2 pieces "Jon" and "es")
3. `3A 80 04034A6F6E1 04026573 0000` (Same as 2. but we do not know the total length ... we just expect 0000 to conclude)

Comment: `If Value is a node (meaning that Value is in fact another Tag/Lenght/Value), Tag's constructed bit is true` -- I would add that it is not always true. `BIT_STRING` and `OCTET_STRING`, for example, can be constructed, but the tag value is primitive (constructed bit is set to 0).

Comment: @Crypt32 Sorry I think you are wrong there. Can you give an example ?

Comment: @Crypt32: In a constructed TLV, the "V" part (called "contents octets" in X.690) consists of a concatenation of (zero or more) TLVs. This is signaled by the "constructed" bit in the "T" part being set to 1. If you have an octet string value that was encoded as a constructed encoding, the "T" part in the TLV corresponding to the octet string value will have its "constructed" bit set to 1, and its "V" part will consist of a concatenation of (zero or more) TLVs. Each of those child TLVs can itself be either primitive or constructed.

Comment: @YaFred @Alessandro, no, it's not. Take a look at X.690 §10.2: `For bitstring, octetstring and restricted character string types, the constructed form of encoding shall not be used. (Contrast with 8.23.6.)`. I think, DER explicitly forbids constructed tags for these types even if they are constructed (have nested ASN types).

Comment: Here is an example when BIT_STRING is used in constructed form (contains nested ASN-encoded types), but encoded in primitive form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUFP.png

Comment: @Crypt32: I was not referring specifically to DER, and the original question didn't mention DER. DER restricts and forbids several things that are allowed in BER, in order to achieve a canonical encoding. Among other things, DER forbids the use of constructed encodings for octet strings, etc. If I am reading you correctly, you can't just use a segmented encoding (nested TLVs) for an octet string value and set the primitive/constructed bit to 0.

Comment: @Crypt: Your example does not show a constructed encoding of a bit string value. A constructed encoding of a bit string value would be one in which the bits of the bit string are split into multiple segments and each segment is encoded into its own TLV, just as if it were itself a bit string value. If I am reading your example correctly, it shows the encoding of a BIT STRING (CONTAINING <<<<some sequence type>>>). In your example, the bits of the bit string consist of the encoding of a sequence value, which is obviously a constructed encoding.

Comment: if you look at screenshot above, there are OCTET_STRINGs with valid nested TLVs, but OCTET_STRING itself is encoded in primitive form. Same with BIT_STRING.

Comment: Please see clause 8.6.3, 8.6.4, etc., of X.690, which specify what is the constructed encoding of a bitstring value. Your example shows a primitive encoding of a bitstring value, not a constructed encoding. The "V" part of your TLV contains just the bits of the bitstring value, with no segmentation. Then (separately) the bit string contains the encoding of a sequence because it's constrained in this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239809/discussion-between-crypt32-and-alessandro).

Comment: Thanks.  But  to my original question, are Sequences always "Constructed"?  Is 0x10 ever a legal tag?  They always seem to be 0x30 even though their is not Explicit prefix and they are not broken up in any unusual way.

Comment: 1/ Yes, when you encode a Sequence, the tag will always have the constructed bit set to true. 2/ As bit 6 is not set in 0x10, 0x10 is NEVER legal for SEQUENCE. 3/ 0x30 is a frequent value for SEQUENCE when you read an encoded value because SEQUENCE univerval tag is 16 (0x10) and when you set bit 6 you'll get 0x30. This is happening when no tagging is specified in your spec.

Comment: When a string is encoded in chunks or with indeterminate length, the outer tag must be constructed.  See X.690 8.6 (`BIT STRING`), 8.6.1, 8.7 (`OCTET STRING`), 8.7.1, etc.  E.g., `8.7.1 The encoding of an octetstring value shall be either primitive or constructed at the option of the sender.` and `NOTE – Where it is necessary to transfer part of an octet string before the entire octetstring is available, the constructed encoding 
is used.` and `8.7.3 The contents octets for the constructed encoding shall consist of zero, one, or more encodings.`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The primitive/constructed bit exists mainly to help that kind of tool like `dumpasn1` that is very "dumb" in that they encode no knowledge of ASN.1 types / modules.  Such tools need to know when the value octets of a tag-length-value might be a sequence of tag-length-value octets so as to have a better chance of producing useful output.

Therefore the BER family of encoding rules marks tags as constructed whenever the value is of a `SEQUENCE`/`SEQUENCE OF`/`SET`/`SET OF` type, as well as whenever the type is explicitly tagged.  (Think of `EXPLICIT` tags as creating something like a `SEQUENCE OF` just one value.)

As well, *string* types can be constructed (in BER, but not DER, and I *think* also not CER) because they can be of indeterminate length when the encoder starts encoding (imagine an encoder that takes a string from `stdin` until `EOF`).  Constructed strings are treated essentially like a `SEQUENCE OF` any number of sub-strings that are notionally concatenated together.

The spec (X.690) itself says this:

> 3.2 constructed encoding: A data value encoding in which the contents octets are the complete encoding of one or more data values.

which I believe matches my explanation.

To recap: constructed means that the value is actually a sequence of zero, one, or more encodings of values, each being tag-length-value.  (X.690, 3.2, says "one or more", but a `SEQUENCE OF`/`SET OF` can be empty, so I believe X.690, 3.2, is in error and should say "zero, one, or more data values"!)